# Zurb Orbit plugin for slideshow with rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, slider, asset-pipeline

I am trying to use Zurb Orbit plugin for a slideshow in my rails application.

I have got a home controller in which I have got index function.

Here is my code :-

index.html.erb

```
<div id="myslider">
  <%=image_tag("slider/pat.jpg")%>
  <%=image_tag("slider/1.jpeg")%>
  <%=image_tag("slider/2.jpeg")%>
</div>
```

home.js

```
$(window).load(function() {
        $('#myslider').orbit();
    });
```

application.html.erb

```
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.orbit.css"%>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.orbit"%>
```

I have included the js file and css file in app/assets folder respectively

But it seems the slideshow is not working. It is a pretty simple stuff I dont know why I am not able to get the slideshow on the page.

The javascript file is getting loaded. what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html file will look like this :-

```
<div id="featured">
  <%=image_tag("slider/pat.jpg")%>
  <%=image_tag("slider/1.jpeg")%>
  <%=image_tag("slider/2.jpeg")%>
</div>
```

The JS file looks like this :-

```
$(window).load(function() {
         $('#featured').orbit();
     });
```

Comment: i think the issue at the time when i wrote it was that it worked only with #featured am not sure though